# How to use Jquery-Comment in Angular 2 and higher

Tags: jquery, angular, npm

I'm using [Jquery-Comment](http://viima.github.io/jquery-comments/) in my Angular 2 project. As explained in there document, I added the script and css file to my **Index.html page** and in script tag I initialize by calling my Comment `TextBox id`. 
While running, I'm getting this error in console.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).comments is not a function

Can any one please tell me how to fix this ? Or is there any other way to add `Jquery-Comment plugin in Angular project using npm` ? I didn't find anything.

I'm initializing Jquery-Comment like this inside my index page,  tag,

```
$('#myCommentTextBoxId').comments({
profilePictureURL: 'https://app.viima.com/static/media/user_profiles/user-
icon.png',
getComments: function(success, error) {
    var commentsArray = [{
        id: 1,
        created: '2015-10-01',
        content: 'Lorem ipsum dolort sit amet',
        fullname: 'Simon Powell',
        upvote_count: 2,
        user_has_upvoted: false
    }];
    success(commentsArray);
}
});
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Hi @David Please check the updated question. I have explained everything as required.

Comment: Try adding that code inside $( document ).ready(), or somewhere in your components

Comment: Since you are using Angular2,  I'm assuming that your using Typescript, probably the error that you are getting it's related to not adding the typings, we need to see more info about the project in order to identify your issue

Comment: Yes! I'm using Typescript, using Visual Code. i'm getting this error in my console. Where I need to add the reference ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you declared jquery variable in your components or typings.d.ts:

```
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;
```

You can install jquery_comments with npm

```
npm install jquery-comments --save
```

If you use angular-cli, you can Add scripts to angular-cli.json, then you don't need to include the scripts/css in index.html

```
"apps": [{
  ...
   "styles": [

    "../node_modules/jquery-comments/css/jquery_comments.css",

  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
     "../node_modules/jquery-comments/js/jquery-comments.js",
  ],
  ...
}]
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this way it will work. Let me check.

Comment: @BasantaMatia did it work, can you please share your experience I am in the same path